# Paypal Adaptive - 3 way paments

Tags: paypal

I have a `wordpress` website I am trying to add `paypal adaptive`.

Where a `paypal` payment goes three ways, from A to B and C (meaning you as the site owner can take your percent from the project in the same paypal payment) normally a `paypal` payment can be only 2 ways, from A to B. I want to enable a three way payment. I already have an `api` signature etc from `paypal`.

1. What do I need to enable this and create a paypal button.?
2. Do I need to download software or a plugin onto the website? please advise?
3. Is it possible for someone to make a paypal payment without a paypal account?
4. How can I set this up?
5. can a paypal window be opened to allow them to just make a payment without having an acocunt?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Adaptive Payments or Express Checkout to receive payments and split the payments up between different accounts.  For example if you are using Express Checkout, you can split the payment up between 10 differet accounts.  The Express Checkout flow allows the buyer to pay with a credit card without having to have a payPal account.  If you would like to direct the buyer directly to the screen where they enter in their credit card information, you would need to pass over the following variables and values in your NVP SetExpressCheckout API call.

```
SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole  
LANDINGPAGE=Billing
```

If you are going to be using Express Checkout or Adaptive Payments, you would not be able to create a simple Website Payments Standard button from within your account.  You would need to make API calls to use these two services.  Express Checkout can be used with a Premiere or a Business account.  There is nothing special that needs to be enabled on the account to start using it.  You can find documentation, code examples, and SDK's on [PayPal Developer Site](http://developer.paypal.com) to help you get started.